# Easier/correct way to resize elements according to screen size

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, button, air, resize

I've got an iOS app thats for all devices. I've designed it perfectly for the iPad but now I'm struggling a bit on resizing elements for smaller screens. My datagrids scale and move perfectly but when it comes to buttons, they just get warped and messed up. The down states on the buttons are massive and stretched and different to the up states. My logic tells me that if I scale the button, it should scale the up and down states accordingly as if you were just resizing on the stage. I'm just trying to make the buttons slightly bigger and move them over a bit..

```
if (Capabilities.screenResolutionX < 700) {
    dg.move(120, 150);
    dg.width = 1120;
    dgPlace.move(70, 20);
    dgPlace.width = 260;
    dgPlace.height = 650;
    dgPlace.rowCount = 21;
    dgPlace.setRendererStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat3);
    dgPlace.setStyle("headerTextFormat", myTextFormat3);
    btnPlacesEditAdd.width = btnPlacesEditAdd.width+20;
    btnPlacesEditAdd.height = btnPlacesEditAdd.height+20;
    btnPlacesEditRemove.width = btnPlacesEditAdd.width+20;
    btnPlacesEditRemove.height = btnPlacesEditAdd.height+20;
    btnPlacesEditSet.width = btnPlacesEditAdd.width+20;
    btnPlacesEditSet.height = btnPlacesEditAdd.height+20;
    btnPlacesEditAdd.x = btnPlacesEditAdd.x+20;
    btnPlacesEditAdd.y = btnPlacesEditAdd.y+20;
    btnPlacesEditSet.x = btnPlacesEditSet.x+20;
    btnPlacesEditSet.y = btnPlacesEditSet.y+20;
    btnPlacesEditRemove.x = btnPlacesEditRemove.x+20;
    btnPlacesEditRemove.y = btnPlacesEditRemove.y+20;
}
```